# how to replace the color entered by the user with my variable in rails?

Tags: html, css

I have already finished my web application is made in ruby on rails, it is an ecommerce platform. What I want to achieve is that from the administrator menu, the admin selects 2 color options, which are the ones that will change the color of the entire site.
I create 2 variables $ color-primary and $ color-secondary. Which are the ones that are in the whole system, so when the user enters those two colors they should be replaced by those colors that have the variables that I create.
Does anyone know how I can achieve it?

Variables.

[image]

Form.

[image]

Comment: You should add the formatted code instead of screenshots

Comment: Now comes the time to use JavaScript. This is that famous variable = getElementByID('ID name').onClick(changeColorFunction(){}). You can write your script on the application.js or creating your custom file.js inside the javascript folder and require it on the application.js

Comment: This kind of thing is not a ruby method. Probably you have already search for a code on ruby to do it, but it is JavaScript function.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should store colour variables in the database. E.g.:

```sh
$ rails g model Color name code
$ rails db:migrate
```

```rb
Color.find_by_name('primary_color').code # => '#fff'
```

2. Add an action to a controller to change this variable in the database.
3. Then, add submit btn to the form and point the form to the action you've just created.
4. Add erb extesion to sass file.
5. Replace `$color-primary` with:

```
<%= Color.find_by_name('primary_color') %>
```

6. I forgot to tell you that you have to regenerate stylesheets each time you update the variables.

```
# app/models/color.rb
class Color < ApplicationRecord
  after_save do
    if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'production'
      # regenerate stylesheets for production
    elsif ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'development'
      # regenerate stylesheets for development
    end
  end
end
```